# Accessing arbitrary rosparam namespaces in Orocos/RTT

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The current rtt_ros_integration (2.5/Electric) only allows RTT components to get/set rosparam params in the namespace corresponding to the name of the component. I could see how this might be desirable to enforce synchronization between rosparam and the component properties, but if I want several components to pull something like an URDF off of the parameter server, it means I need to load it each time. This clutters both the parameter server and launchfiles. Is this a design decision or would a patch be welcomed to enable something like:

```
loadService("my_component","rosparam")
my_component.rosparam.refreshProperties("/some/arbitrary/namespace")
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31792/accessing-arbitrary-rosparam-namespaces-in-orocos/rtt/) by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5809 on 2012-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As shown on the wiki page (http://www.ros.org/wiki/rtt_ros_param ), it is possible to load parameters from other places than the /nodename/componentname namespace: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rtt_ros_param#Refresh_a_single_properties

I do have to admit that there is no possibility yet to load it from an arbitrary namespace. A patch to provide this extra functionality is always welcome.

Ruben

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) with karma: 543 on 2012-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0